# saving the dynamically added textboxes in php

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, tablerow

hi i am working on a form which has an ability to add table rows on button click but the problem is that the my php for loop is saving the first row and not saving the other textboxe values. i am stuck. here is my code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="invoice" method="POST">
        <div id="div-2" class="accordion-body collapse in body">
                <div style="max-height:300px;overflow: auto; border: 0px solid;">
                <div style="float:left; margin-right:-8220000px;">   
            <table id="data" border="1px" width="90%">

                <tr>
                    <td width="60px" align="center"> <label class="control-label">Sr No.</label></td>
                    <td width="250px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Item Name</label></td>
                    <td width="90px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Qty</label></td>
                    <td width="50px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Unit</label></td>
                    <td width="100px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Rate</label></td>
                    <td width="120px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Amount</label></td>
                    <td width="200px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Marks& Nos</label></td>
                    <td width="250px" align="center"><label class="control-label">Description</label></td>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" maxlength="6" name="srno_0" class="sno form-control"/></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <select data-placeholder="Item"  name="item_0" class="form-control"  >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <?php
                                    $mown = mysql_query("SELECT code, `name` FROM `item`") or die(mysql_error());
                                    while ($trow = mysql_fetch_array($mown)) {
                                           echo "<option value=$trow[code]>$trow[name]</option>";
                                    }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="qty_0" class="qty form-control" style='text-align:right'/></td>
                        <td align="left">
                            <input type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" name="unit_0" class="unit form-control"/>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="rate_0" class="rate form-control" style='text-align:right'/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6" maxlength="9" maxlength="6" name="amt_0" id="amount" class="amt form-control" style='text-align:right' readonly/></td>
                        <td align="center"><input type="text" size="6"  name="marks_0" class="trip form-control"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><textarea name="descrip_0" cols="90" rows='1' class="desc form-control"></textarea></td>

                    </tr>
   </table>
            </div>  

    </div>
            <table border='0' width='100%'>


        <tr>
            <td width="150px">
                <input type="button" id="addnew" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" name="addnew" value="+" />
                       <input type="hidden" id="items" name="items" value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $ctr : 1; ?>" />  
</td><td width="240px"></td><td width="140px"></td><td width="200px" align="right"><label for=""><font color="black" size="3px">SubTotal</font><span></span></label></td>
            <td width="200px"><input id="total" type="text" name="total" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo ($addflag == 0) ? $get['total'] : "0.00"; ?>" readonly style='text-align:right'></td>
        </tr>
    here is my jquery code
  <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#data').on('keyup', '.qty, .rate, .amt', calculateRow);
                $('#data').on('blur', '.desc', addrows);

                  function addrows(){    

                   var ctr = $('#items').val();
                    $.post('bmt_invsrch.php', {ctr: ctr}, function(data) {
                        $(data).appendTo('#data');
                        ctr++;
                        $('#items').val(ctr);
                    });
                }

                $('#addnew').click(function() {
                       addrows();
                });
            });


        </script>
```

here is my php

```
for ($i = 0; $i<$count; $i++){
    $msrno         = $_POST["srno_$i"];
    $mitem         = $_POST["item_$i"];
    $mqty          = $_POST["qty_$i"];
    $munit         = $_POST["unit_$i"];
    $mrate         = $_POST["rate_$i"];
    $mamt          = $_POST["amt_$i"];
    $mmarks        = $_POST["marks_$i"];
    $mdescrip      = $_POST["descrip_$i"];

         mysql_query("INSERT INTO `saletran`(vouchno, srno, item, qty, unit, rate, amt, marks, descrip)
                     VALUES('$mvouch', '$msrno', '$mitem', '$mqty', '$munit', '$mrate', '$mamt', '$mmarks', '$mdescrip')") or die(mysql_error());



}
```

Comment: Your code is wide open to sql injections. Please follow the general advice, stop using the old and depricated mysql extensions, switch to mysqli and use prepared statements.

Comment: We cannot say much without additional data. First step: check what really is contained in the $_POST superglobal variable. Dump it or check with a debugger.

Comment: i cheked it the added values are not being transferred in it

Comment: We're not going to read through that wall of html/php/javascsript. You need to reduce to a REPRESENTATIVE code sample.

Comment: SEE I HAVE REDUCED MY CODE

Comment: Ok, so if those attributes are _not_ sent then you have a client side problem. Next step: check how the attributes are named (the dynamically created ones...). Do so by using the development console of your browser. Check the DOM tree, look for the attributes, make sure the names follow the naming scheme you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can group you input fields, something like this

```
<form method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='test[]' />
  <input type='text' name='test[]' />
  <input type='text' name='test[]' />
  <input type='text' name='test[]' />

  <input type='submit' value='submit' name='submit'/>
</form>
```

When you submit this form the result will be something like

```
Array
(
  [test] => Array
      (
          [0] => 21
          [1] => 212
          [2] => 121
          [3] => 21
      )

  [submit] => submit
)
```